# Calculo entre dois inputs e resultado em outro

Tags: javascript, jquery

O script abaixo funciona somente para o primeiro bloco ao se digitar a quantidade.

Existe algum modo da função realizar o calculo dependendo do bloco em que se digita a quantidade.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.somente-numero').keyup(function (e) {
     $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
     var v1 = Number(document.getElementById("v1").value);
     var v2 = Number(document.getElementById("v2").value);
     var v7 = document.getElementById("v7").value = parseFloat(v1 * v2).toFixed(2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bloco 1 -->
<label>preço</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[0][valor_org]" id="v1" size="10" value="100.00"/> 
<label>quantidade</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[0][quantidade]" id="v2" size="10"/> 
<label>total</label> <input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[0][valor_total_prod]" id="v7" size="10" readonly />

<br>

<!-- bloco 2 -->
<label>preço</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_org]" id="x1" size="10" value="200.00"/> 
<label>quantidade</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[1][quantidade]" id="x2" size="10"/> 
<label>total</label> <input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_total_prod]" id="x7" size="10" readonly />

 <!-- bloco 3 -->

 .................

 <!-- bloco n -->
```

Comment: Leo, os inputs possuiram mesmo nome (exemplo: `name="quantidade"`)?

Comment: @CaiqueRomero, os names são diferentes, editei a pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução sem alterar nada no seu HTML é pegando o `index` do campo digitado pelo `name` e jogando o valor no campo *total* de mesmo *index*.

O `e.target.name.split('[').pop()` irá retornar ou `valor_org]` ou `quantidade]`, que já é suficiente para saber o *index* do elemento que está sendo digitado usando `input[name*=`, que seleciona o campo que contém uma das *strings* acima no `name`.

> **Obs.:** o `parseFloat` se torna desnecessário, já que os valores foram convertidos em `Number()` anteriormente.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.somente-numero').keyup(function (e) {
      $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
      // aqui eu pego o index
      var idx = $('input[name*="'+e.target.name.split('[').pop()+'"]').index(this);
      var v1 = Number($($('input[name*="[valor_org]"]')[idx]).val());
      var v2 = Number($($('input[name*="[quantidade"]')[idx]).val());
      $($('input[name*="[valor_total_prod]"]')[idx]).val((v1 * v2).toFixed(2));
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bloco 1 -->
<label>preço</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[0][valor_org]" id="v1" size="10" value="100.00"/> 
<label>quantidade</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[0][quantidade]" id="v2" size="10"/> 
<label>total</label> <input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[0][valor_total_prod]" id="v7" size="10" readonly />

<br>

<!-- bloco 2 -->
<label>preço</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_org]" id="x1" size="10" value="200.00"/> 
<label>quantidade</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[1][quantidade]" id="x2" size="10"/> 
<label>total</label> <input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_total_prod]" id="x7" size="10" readonly />
```

Comment: +1 Boa observação

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro eu coloquei um nome igual para todos os `input` e adicionei diferentes classes para cada bloco.

Na função eu identifico a qual classe(bloco) pretence o input alterado e assim sei que o total daquele bloco deve ser atualizado.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.somente-numero').keyup(function (e) {
 $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
  
  //Obtenho a qual bloco pertence o elemento alterado
  //Pegando a segunda classe do elemento
  var classeBloco = $(this).attr("class").split(' ')[1];
  
  //Obtenho o total daquele bloco
  var $total = $(".total"+classeBloco);

  //Obtenho o preço daquele bloco
  var $preco = $("input."+classeBloco+"[name='preco']").val();
  
  //Obtenho a quantidade daquele bloco
  var $qtd = $("input."+classeBloco+"[name='quantidade']").val();

  $total.val((Number($preco) * Number($qtd)).toFixed(2));
  
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- bloco 1 -->
<div>
  <label>Preço</label> 
  <input type="text" class="somente-numero bloco1" name="preco" size="10" value="100.00"/> 

  <label>quantidade</label>
  <input type="text" class="somente-numero bloco1" name="quantidade" size="10"/> 

  <label>total</label> 
  <input type="text" name="total" class="totalbloco1" size="10" readonly />
</div>

<!-- bloco 2 -->
<div>
  <label>Preço</label> 
  <input type="text" class="somente-numero bloco2" name="preco" size="10" value="200.00"/> 

  <label>quantidade</label> 
  <input type="text" class="somente-numero bloco2" name="quantidade" size="10"/> 

  <label>total</label> 
  <input type="text" name="total" class="totalbloco2" size="10" readonly />
</div>

<!-- bloco 3 -->
<div>
  <label>Preço</label> 
  <input type="text" class="somente-numero bloco3" name="preco" size="10" value="200.00"/> 

  <label>quantidade</label> 
  <input type="text" class="somente-numero bloco3" name="quantidade" size="10"/> 

  <label>total</label> 
  <input type="text" name="total" class="totalbloco3" size="10" readonly />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui lá com os [**brothers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979456/calculation-between-two-inputs-and-result-in-another/47979703#47979703) dessa forma e vou publicar aqui porque achei interessante.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.somente-numero').keyup(function (e) {
        var currentVal = $(this).val();
        var replaceD = currentVal.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
        $(this).val(replaceD);
        var v1 = Number($(this).prev().prev().val());
        var v2 = Number($(this).val());
        var calculatedval = parseFloat(v1 * v2).toFixed(2);
        $(this).next().next().val(calculatedval);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- bloco 1 -->
<label>preço</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[0][valor_org]" id="v1" size="10" value="100.00"/> 
<label>quantidade</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[0][quantidade]" id="v2" size="10"/> 
<label>total</label> <input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[0][valor_total_prod]" id="v7" size="10" readonly />

<br>

<!-- bloco 2 -->
<label>preço</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_org]" id="x1" size="10" value="200.00"/> 
<label>quantidade</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[1][quantidade]" id="x2" size="10"/> 
<label>total</label> <input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_total_prod]" id="x7" size="10" readonly />

<br>

<!-- bloco 3 -->
<label>preço</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_org]" id="x1" size="10" value="10.00"/> 
<label>quantidade</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[1][quantidade]" id="x2" size="10"/> 
<label>total</label> <input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_total_prod]" id="x7" size="10" readonly />
```